# C# / ASP.NET Core 6 : transform weird json to something useful

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-6.0

I get a JSON from a webrequest:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var json = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<dynamic>(url);
```

The JSON I get looks like this (I have no control over this, so can't change it):

```
{
    "1": {
        "2023-03-10": [
            {
                "label": "AAA",
                "prop1": 123,
                "prop2": 456,
            },
            {
                "label": "BBB",
                "prop1": 123,
                "prop2": 456,
            },
            {
                "label": "CCC",
                "prop1": 123,
                "prop2": 456,
            }
        ],
        "2023-03-11": [
            {
                "label": "CCC",
                "prop1": 123,
                "prop2": 456,
            },
            {
                "label": "DDD",
                "prop1": 123,
                "prop2": 456,
            }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "2023-03-10": [...],
        "2023-03-11": [...]
    },
   ...
   ...
}
```

Note that "1", "2" and the dates are ***not*** elements in an array.

How do I even work with this?

Can I loop over it in some way?

```
foreach(var item in json?.somethingGetAllProperties()?)
{
    var id = item?.what?
}
```

Or can I transform it to something I can use?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var json = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<MyObject>(url, new JsonSerializerOptions(){ ?what? });

[?SomethingHere?]
class MyObject
{
    [?OrHere?]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Baa> Baa{ get; set; }
}

class Baa 
{
    public string label{ get; set; }
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have only used simple json transformation before. Like changing the name of an attribute to something new.

Comment: Instead of dynamic, you could use a dictionary or JsonDocument.

Comment: Checkout the duplicate. Use nested dictionaries in this case, something like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Baa[]>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simpliest way is to use a dictionary

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
                               Dictionary<string,List<Props>>>>(json);

string label=data["1"]["2023-03-11"][0].label; //"CCC"

//or 
List<Props> props20230311 = data["1"]["2023-03-11"].Select(x => x).ToList();

public class Props
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

or you can use a strictly typed list, but it is much more complicated

```
List<CountDateProps> props = JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
    .Select(jo => new CountDateProps
    {
        Count = jo.Name,
        DateProps = ((JObject)jo.Value).Properties().Select(v => new DateProps
        {
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(v.Name),
            Props = v.Value.ToObject<List<Props>>()
        }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        
List<Props> props20230310 = props.Where(p=> p.Count=="1").First()
                                .DateProps.Where(v=> v.Date== new DateTime(2023,03,11))
                                .FirstOrDefault().Props;    
    
public class CountDateProps
{
    public string Count {get;set;}
    public List<DateProps> DateProps { get; set; }
    
}
public class DateProps
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Props> Props {get; set;}
}
```